# obtaining a rowcount when running python cursor.execute on Redshift for UNLOAD command

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Title says it all really. When I call the unload through a cursor, it works great. However when I try to obtain the record count for how many unloaded, it returns -1. This corresponds to the documentation I suppose (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html,   "-1...row count of the last operation if it can’t be determined by the interface")

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
ext_cur = connection.cursor()
ext_cur.execute("unload ('Select * from test;') to 's3://test/test_output_191121215843.txt' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxx' delimiter as '|' PARALLEL OFF  HEADER ALLOWOVERWRITE;")
Print(str(ext_cur.rowcount()))
```

But I wonder if anyone has found a work around? (short of downloading the file from S3 and running a row count!).
When I run the same unload command from a desktop db tool like DBVisualizer, **it shows the number of rows unloaded**. So **I have to believe** there is a way to get it from the database..

Example response from DBVisulizer log window:

```
17:44:03  [UNLOAD - 0 rows, 0.955 secs]  Command processed. No rows were affected
SQL State: 01000 --- UNLOAD completed, 471 record(s) unloaded successfully.
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 rows affected, exec/fetch time: 0.955/0.000 sec  [1 successful, 1 SQL warnings, 0 errors]
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it.. after running the unload, call:

```
select pg_last_unload_count();
```

(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_LAST_UNLOAD_COUNT.html)